# ipywidgets and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

How I can get dataframe out of @interact function for next cell?
My interact function looks something like this:

```
@interact(eutPlace=eutPlaces)
def selectByEut (eutPlace):
    rdsTable = tabelSisse.drop(['Id', 'Serial_number', 'User_modified'], axis='columns')
    rdsTable = rdsTable.loc[rdsTable['EUT_place'] == eutPlace]
    print(rdsTable.shape)
    return rdsTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Found one solution. Use interactive instead of @interact.

```
def selectByEut (eutPlace):
    rdsTable = tabelSisse.drop(['Id', 'Serial_number', 'User_modified'], axis='columns')
    rdsTable = rdsTable.loc[rdsTable['EUT_place'] == eutPlace]
    display(rdsTable)
    return rdsTable

intrFilt = interactive(selectByEut, eutPlace=eutPlaces)
intrFilt
```

And in the next cell i can get the resulting dataframe with:

```
reducedTable = intrFilt.result
```